# How to obtain a 3D context for Google Native Client

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine, google-nativeclient

Ever since Chromium/Native Client have switched to using PPAPI 2, obtaining a 3D context is broken. I can link and compile my application (which uses OpenGL ES 2 extensively), everything works ... except obtaining a 3D context to draw on. My problems are exactly the same as in this [ML post](https://groups.google.com/group/native-client-discuss/browse_thread/thread/67cc0906801cb1b4). This problem exists at least with NaCl SDK 2, and 3, both with chrome 11, and 12. Now I know because of the API changes, gl is simply not supported at the moment. However, I believe there are other projects actively working on 3D ports to NaCl (ex. [Unity](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2011/06/02/notes-on-native-client-pepper-plugin-api/%20Unity)), and I assume they have some kludge to obtain the context. Of course it is also possible that they are developing with an old version of Chrome/NaCl, or that they have put development on hold until the API catches up.

Basically, my question is, is there any kludge I can use to obtain the 3D context to use with opengl es 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, when NaCL moved to pepper it broke (and put into Dev) the 3D API.  However with newer versions of the SDK (those targeting Chrome / PPAPI 16 and up) this is working again.

More recent versions of the NaclSDK's have a simple 3D sample called Tumbler, which has a class OpenGLContext, which shows how to get your 3D context working in newer versions of Native Client.